# Having the HTML of a webpage, how to obtain the visible words of that webpage?

Tags: html

Having the HTML of a webpage, what would be the easiest strategy to get the text that's visible on the correspondent page? I have thought of getting everything that's between the `<a>..</a>` and `<p>...</p>` but that is not working that well.

Keep in mind as that this is for a school project, I am not allowed to use any kind of external library (the idea is to have to do the parsing myself). Also, this will be implemented as the HTML of the page is downloaded, that is, I can't assume I already have the whole HTML page downloaded. It has to be showing up the extracted visible words as the HTML is being downloaded.

Also, it doesn't have to work for ALL the cases, just to be satisfatory most of the times.

Comment: and what programming language are you using?

Comment: Is that the entirety of the requirements, "the text that's visible"? Because, as posed, that seems like a hard problem for a school assignment. (And you should add a "homework" tag to your post.)

Comment: Relax, it doesn't have to get ALL the text for ALL sites. I just want a general approach that'll work for most of the cases. The focus of the project is not even on getting the visible text, it's on software architecture (I'll implement this with Pipe&Filter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally all the text that is *visible* sounds like a big ask for a school project, as it would depend not only on the HTML itself, but also any in-page or external styling. One solution would be to simply strip the HTML tags from the input, though that wouldn't strictly meet your requirements as you have stated them.

Assuming that near enough is good enough, you could make a first pass to strip out the content of entire elements which you know won't be visible (such as `script`, `style`), and a second pass to remove the remaining tags themselves.

Comment: I am doing this for a software architecture course. The focus is not on having it give me 100.000% correct results. I am just looking for a way to get most of the visible text, if possible. It doesn't have to be anything too fancy.

Comment: Stripping the HTML tags will not put what is inside <script> as visibile text?

Comment: Yes, it would. You will need to account for special cases like that.

Comment: So, I'd need prior to stripping HTML tags, to remove <script> tags. That doesn't seem like a big problem. Any other kinds of tags I should completly remove before the processing, other than the <script> tag?

Comment: Presumably everything in the <head> (maybe with the exception of <title>), for a start.

Answer (score 3):

> I am not allowed to use any kind of external library

This is a poor requirement for a ‘software architecture’ course. Parsing HTML is *extremely difficult* to do correctly—certainly *way* outside the bounds of a course exercise. Any naïve approach you come up involving regex hacks is going to fall over badly on common web pages.

The software-architecturally correct thing to do here is use an external library that has already solved the problem of parsing HTML (such as, for .NET, the HTML Agility Pack), and then iterate over the document objects it generates looking for text nodes that aren't in ‘invisible’ elements like `<script>`.

If the task of grabbing data from web pages is of your own choosing, to demonstrate some other principle, then I would advise picking a different challenge, one you can usefully solve. For example, just changing the input from HTML to XML might allow you to use the built-in XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

i'd consider writing regex to remove all html tags and you should be left with your desired text. This can be done in Javascript and doesn't require anything special.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not exactly what you asked for, but it can be done using Regular Expressions:

```
//javascript code
//should (could) work in C# (needs escaping for quotes) :
h = h.replace(/<(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*>/g,'');
```

This RegExp will remove HTML tags, notice however that you first need to remove script,link,style,... tags.

If you decide to go this way, I can help you with the regular expressions needed.

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 includes a detailed description of [how to build a parser](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/parsing.html#parsing). It is probably more complicated then you are looking for, but it is the recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to parse every DOM element for text, and then detect whether that DOM element is visible (`el.style.display == 'block'` or `'inline'`), and then you'll need to detect whether that element is positioned in such a manner that it isn't outside of the viewable area of the page. Then you'll need to detect the `z-index` of each element and the background of each element in order to detect if any overlapping is hiding some text.

Basically, this is impossible to do within a month's time.